# Meteor - Reactive Objects/Classes

Tags: meteor, meteor-helper

**TLDR**

I like to really focus on keeping business logic away from the view model / controller. I find this sometimes rather hard in Meteor. Maybe I'm missing the point but I am after one of two things really:

1) A really good document explaining at a really low level how reactive values are being used. 
2) A package that somehow manages an object so that if any of the setters are altered, they notify all of the get functions that would change as a result.

Unfortunately I've not seen either.

**My Example**

I have a fair bit ob business logic sitting behind a dialog used to document a *consultation*. I might have an event that sets a change of state.

I'd like to do something like this in the event:

```
const cc = new ConsultationEditor();
cc.setChiefComplaint(event.target.value);
console.log(cc.data());
ConsultationDict.set("consEdit", cc.data() );
```

When the user has updated this value, I'd then like to show a number of fields, based on the change. For this I have a helper with the following:

```
fields: function(){
  console.log("trying to get fields");
  const obj = ConsultationDict.get('consEdit');
  cc = new ConsultationEditor(obj);
  return cc.getFields();
}
```

But unfortunately this does not work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your `ConsultationDict`?

The way you describe it, you want it  to be a `ReactiveDict` as in the official ReactiveDict package.

https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/reactive-dict

Check this tutorial for examples:

https://themeteorchef.com/snippets/reactive-dict-reactive-vars-and-session-variables/

If you really need more fine tuning in your reactivity, you can also set a dependency tracker `tracker = new Tracker.Dependency`, and then refer to it wherever you change a variable with `tracker.changed()` and where the data needs to be notified with `tracker.depend()` like this:

```
var favoriteFood = "apples";
var favoriteFoodDep = new Tracker.Dependency;

var getFavoriteFood = function () {
  favoriteFoodDep.depend();
  return favoriteFood;
};

var setFavoriteFood = function (newValue) {
  favoriteFood = newValue;
  favoriteFoodDep.changed();
};

getFavoriteFood();
```

See the full Tracker doc here:

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Tracker-Manual

I also found this gist to be useful to build reactive objects:

https://gist.github.com/richsilv/7d66269aab3552449a4c

and for a ViewModel type of behavior, check out

https://viewmodel.meteor.com/

I hope this helps.

Comment: The `ConsultationDict` is a reactive dict. I got it working but something was odd at the time I wrote the above and I cannot replicate it now after making other changes. Sorry.